# Why bi-directional ManyToOne causes circular dependency in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have entities in my project(based on `Spring-Boot` + `Hibernate`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserRole role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userAccount", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<RentInfo> rents;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rent_info")
public class RentInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserAccount userAccount;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
}
```

I want to create bi-directional one-to-many relation, when one user can have several rents and when we can select rents by concrete user_id, but something goes wrong

In response I get this:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "userName": "test@mail.loc",
        "firstName": "fName",
        "lastName": "lName",
        "password": "test",
        "birthday": "2001-11-03T14:28:14",
        "role": {
            "name": "CLIENT"
        },
        "rents": [
            {
                "userAccount": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "userName": "test@mail.loc",
                    "firstName": "fName",
                    "lastName": "lName",
                    "password": "test",
                    "birthday": "2001-11-03T14:28:14",
                    "role": {
                        "name": "CLIENT"
                    },
                    "rents": [
                        {
                            "userAccount": {
                                "id": 1,
                                "userName": "test@mail.loc",
                                "firstName": "fName",
                                "lastName": "lName",
                                "password": "test",
                                "birthday": "2001-11-03T14:28:14",
                                "role": {
                                    "name": "CLIENT"
                                }
    .....
```

And this is unlimited and logically I have out of memory error. How can I fix this? what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `@OneToMany` relationships are lazy by default. Use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` only for `@ManyToOne`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two solutions :

1. Use @JsonIgnore on the @ManyToOne
2. Do NOT serialize your entities. Use DTOs instead and take care while mapping to avoid circular dependencies

Comment: To rephrase option #2: Instead of serializing the JPA-annotated entity class to JSON, you could map the entity to a separate class (commonly referred to as a Data Transfer Object or DTO). In the mapping process you have to solve the cycle issue yourself (e.g. by not mapping rent.userAccount

Comment: thank you very much.this solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to solve this infinite recursion problem as follows:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    private LocalDateTime birthday;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserRole role;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userAccount", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<RentInfo> rents;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "rent_info")
public class RentInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private UserAccount userAccount;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private LocalDateTime startDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private LocalDateTime endDate;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private int status;
}
```

Nevertheless, I would first map your entities to DTOs. However, you might as well need to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` in these new DTO classes if you want all data to be available (one way to avoid this infinite recursion problem would be not mapping `userAccount` in `RentInfoDto` but you might not want that because you also want to serialize `UserAccountDto` data).