# The Parent entity inside child entity pull the child again

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

When I try to fetch the child entity, it also gets the parent entity because of one to many bidirectional mapping but the parent entity inside the child again pulling its child. which need to be avoided

Parent entity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Students> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Child Entity

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
private School school;
```

While I hit the get call of child entity the response is like

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "lastName": "lastname",
    "age": "20",
    "school": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "testName",
        "description": "school",
        "studentsList": [
            1
        ]
    }
}
```

***But the expected response is**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "firstname",
    "lastName": "lastname",
    "age": "20",
    "school": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "testName",
        "description": "school"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Understood your problem you may use the @JsonIgnoreProperties({}) Annations.

For Example:
In parent Object like this

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"school"})
private List<Students> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This fix my problem but i have do in reverse order

 `@ManyToOne(optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "school_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({"studentsList "})
  private School school; `

Answer (score 0):

Use "Eager" fetch.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Students> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Same result, but why i need to do that.. my requirement is to avoid the "studentsList":[1] from response

Comment: I misunderstood your question. What I did to take out circular calls was not to use @ManyToOne(optional = false) in Child. Another solution was to use @JsonManagedResource as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825669/why-bi-directional-manytoone-causes-circular-dependency-in-hibernate

Comment: Yep i tried this already. if i use this it is not allowing me to save the parent entity along with child entity